# How can I use postsave method extending WebformHandlerBase for submitting to account fields

Tags: forms, hooks, webforms

I created a webform handler class extending from WebFormHandlerBase: The method, postsave has the following code:

```
public function postSave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, $update = TRUE) {
    $account = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($account->id());
    $user->addRole('example');
    $user->save();
  }
```

A boolean and photo value are submitted by the webform submission.  I need to submit the boolean and photo to account fields.  How do I do it?

Comment: get the data from the webform_submission object and then save it to whatever properties? It may help you tremendously to rely on a IDE (such as phpstorm, netbeans, visual studio code) to inspect and debug code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$account = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($account->id());
    $data = $webform_submission->getData();
    $photo = $data['picture'];
    $user->set('field_photo', $photo);
    $user->save();
  }
**The above code, for example, will take a webform element, key is 'picture' and set it to an account field, 'field_photo'.**